# make error when change one parameter

Tags: gcc, makefile, position

To bypass a length limit, the author tells me:

> To build for a higher limit, you can change the Makefile setting
>   `-Dmax_sequence_index=32` to `-Dmax_sequence_index=63`.
>   This is around line 58 in the Makefile".

When I change it I have got an error:

```
gcc -c -O3 -Wall -Wextra -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DVERSION_MAJOR=&quot;\&quot;1&quot;\&quot; -DVERSION_MINOR=&quot;\&quot;04&quot;\&quot; -DVERSION_SUBMINOR=&quot;\&quot;00&quot;\&quot; -DREVISION_DATE=&quot;\&quot;20170312&quot;\&quot; -DSUBVERSION_REV=&quot;\&quot;1881:1893M&quot;\&quot; -Dmax_sequence_index=63 -Dmax_malloc_index=40 -Ddiag_hash_size=4194304 pos_table.c -o pos_table_32.o
pos_table.c:1763:6: error: conflicting types for &#39;limit_position_table&#39;
 void limit_position_table
      ^
In file included from pos_table.c:31:0:
pos_table.h:248:11: note: previous declaration of &#39;limit_position_table&#39; was here
 void      limit_position_table      (postable* pt, u32 limit, u32 maxChasm);
           ^
make: *** [pos_table_32.o] Error 1
```

I think I should also change another two files: `pos_table.c` and `pos_table.h`. This two files can be seen here: https://github.com/lastz/lastz/tree/master/src

Answer (score 0):

This is a synchronization error between header file and source file.

The `max_sequence_index` flag [is used to generate types](https://github.com/lastz/lastz/blob/master/src/sequences.h#L65), including the `unspos` type.

In the [`pos_table.h`](https://github.com/lastz/lastz/blob/master/src/pos_table.h#L248) header file the signature is:

```c
void limit_position_table(postable* pt, u32 limit, u32 maxChasm);
```

But in the [`pos_table.c`](https://github.com/lastz/lastz/blob/master/src/pos_table.c#L1763) source file we have got:

```c
void limit_position_table(postable* pt, u32 _limit, unspos maxChasm) {
    ...
}
```

So, to solve this issue, you will have to edit the `pos_table.h` header file, and to modify the signature to fit with the one in the source file.